# Rewrite rule, simple OR in hostname check

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i´m searching for something obvious simple
but i´m not able to find the syntax around the web

so i have conditions like that :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?some-domain.com$ [NC]
```

and i want to check for several hostnames, like this pseudocode :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(some-domain.com|someother-domain.com)$ [NC]
```

but somehow its not working

i´m no htaccess pro at all so i would be very thankfull if someone could point me to the right way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(some-domain|someother-domain)\.com$ [NC]
```

Keep common part of regex outside `(..)` and escape the dots which could match any character otherwise.

Comment: somehow this work if host is `some-domain` but if host is `someother-domain` it simply ignores this rule, any idea ?

Comment: well, what if i have different top level domains ? when i use it like this `^(www\.)?(some-domaine.de|someother-domain.com)\$` it wont work

Comment: Use of `\$` is wrong since it will match literal `$`. You can use in that case: `^(www\.)?(some-domaine\.de|someother-domain\.com)$`